# I want to output GoogleChart to PDF

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, erb

The target file is erb.I have used the sample code to see if it will display, but it is not displaying properly.If anyone knows what to do, I would be happy to get some advice on how to think about it!

**Version/Library**

ruby 2.6.6

Rails 6.0.3.6

wicked_pdf (2.1.0)

wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.12.6.5)

**I tried**

1. Convert erb to html file and check if graph is displayed

- Result: Graph is displayed -> Graph implementation is complete except for the implementation of drawing to PDF.

2. Write javascript_delay: 3000 and check if the graph is displayed

- Result: No change as shown .

**Reference URL**

GoogleChart Sample Code

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start?hl=ja

Wicked_pdf GitHub

https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

**code**

```
■ app/views/pdf/test.pdf.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #chart_div { height: 400px; width: 1400px; min-height: 150px; }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    テストです
  </body>

</html>
```

```
■ app/services/pdf/pdf_service.rb

class Pdf::PdfService
# "only the part related to PDF is described"
  attr_reader :file_path :hoge, :data

  def initialize file_path, hoge
    @file_path = file_path

    # "Omitted as it is irrelevant to the graph."
    @data = {}

    def perform!    
      html = ActionController::Base.render file_path: file_path, assigns: data
      WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        html,
        # WickedPdf_options:PDFのタイトル名
        pdf: '診断結果.pdf',
        encoding: 'utf-8',
        margin: {top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0},
        orientation: 'Landscape',
        javascript_delay: 3000
      )
    rescue StandardError => e
      Rails.logger.error e.message
      false
    end
  end
end
```

```
■ app/controllers/api/v1/test_controller.rb

# "only relevant parts of the graph in the PDF are described"
def pdf_dawnload
    file_path = "pdf/test.pdf"
    hoge = hoge.find(params[:hoge_id])
    pdf_raw = Pdf::PdfService.new(file_path, hoge).perform!
    send_data(pdf_raw)
  end
end
```

```
■ config/routes.rb
# "only HTTP status is described"
get 'pdf_dawnload/:hoge_id' ,to: 'test#pdf_dawnload'
```

Comment: This [bug report](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4733) suggest that using an [older release](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#Releases) might work, e.g. `google.charts.load('43', ...)`

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Mr.Stefan.
I will try to respond to your article.

Answer (score 0):

Just an aside, but the `wkhtmltopdf` library used by the `wicked_pdf` gem isn't really current with respect to web standards (see https://wkhtmltopdf.org/status.html).

You may have more luck doing the final rendering to PDF using the `grover` gem, as it uses a more up-to-date headless browser (as opposed to an older version of webkit).

Where I work we've found `wkhtmltopdf` to be incompatible with a lot of modern CSS mechanisms (flex and the like) and have had to write completely separate stylesheets for PDF rendering.